# Scala Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: scala, classcastexception

My query is like

```
val demo = spark.sql(s"select PERCENTILE_APPROX(weight,array(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)) from db.demo_input_data")
scala> demo.first.getList(0)
res0: java.util.List[Nothing] = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

My ultimate goal is to get data from following command

```
scala> val BenchmarkPercentile = ":10"
scala> demo.first.getList(0).map((x: Double) => x + BenchmarkPercentile)
```

When I run this command I get following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:114)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
  ... 51 elided
```

On the other hand if my dataset is different where if I get following data, command works fine

```
scala> val demo1 = spark.sql(s"select PERCENTILE_APPROX(weight,array(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)) from db.demo_input_data1")
scala> demo1.first.getList(0)
res1: java.util.List[Nothing] = [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

Please help me understand why is this behaviour.
NOTE:- I have also issued below command before running above code

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to handle the correct types. I mean, your sql query creates a dataframe with a specific schema. In your case, you create the demo1 dataframe and get the first row. Then, the first column as a java.util.List, so you are taking your dataframe to the jvm(Scala types) world. Because Dataframe api is untyped, unlike the Dataset api, you have to deal with that type mismatch manually:

```
 demo.first.getList(0).map((x: BigDecimal) => x + BenchmarkPercentile)
```

take a look to the Spar doc regarding types: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html

Comment: Thank you Emiliano. I checked and you are right the data type in both dataframes was different. In one it was Double and in another it was BigDecimal. Thats why it was breaking. Thanks again